# Cannot move TM1637 from Uno to Pro Mini

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-pro-mini, display

I have a very simple setup which works fine with an *Uno*.

[image]

```
#include <SevenSegmentTM1637.h>
#include <SevenSegmentExtended.h>

const byte PIN_CLK = 2;
const byte PIN_DIO = 3;
SevenSegmentExtended display(PIN_CLK, PIN_DIO);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  display.begin();
  display.print(F("TEST"));
}

void loop() {}
```

When I use the very same setup with a *Pro Mini* (XCSOURCE ATMEGA 328P, 5V 16Mhz), the display doesn't light up. I get monitor outputs and can blink the onboard LED, but no reaction from the *TM1637* display.

I get this output in the console:

```
�E%MA1e� 10001111
Acknowledged: 0
ADDR :  11000000
DATA0:  0
write byte: 84
ADDR :  11000000
DATA0:  1111000
write byte: 69
ADDR :  11000000
DATA0:  1111000
write byte: 83
ADDR :  11000000
DATA0:  1111000
write byte: 84
ADDR :  11000000
DATA0:  1111000
```

Does anyone have an idea how to debug or fix this?

Comment: Could you please post a schematic?

Comment: I just added it to my original question.

Comment: You haven't created the display object. Shouldn't you have a line somewhere that creates the object:
SevenSegmentTM1637    display(PIN_CLK, PIN_DIO);

Comment: Yes, sorry. I forgot to copy that in. I edited the question now.

Comment: What would be the output of the console on an UNO?

Comment: Include library link please

Comment: It doesn't appear that the code segment you posted corresponds to the actual code that creates the listed serial monitor output. Can you show the actual code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using a Grove Display, I believe it will be using I2C.

For better debugging, try using the actual I2C pins on your Pro mini, which are A4 and A5.

> I2C: A4 (SDA) and A5 (SCL). Support I2C (TWI) communication using the
>   Wire library.
>   https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardProMini

I2C may need pull-up resistors on your data lines.

(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2C)

It can also be nice to use "verified to be working" code, like example code from the manufacturer.

```
/*
 * TM1637.cpp
 * A library for the 4 digit display
 */
#include "TM1637.h"
#define CLK 39 //pins definitions for TM1637 and can be changed to other ports
#define DIO 38
TM1637 tm1637(CLK,DIO);
void setup()
{
    tm1637.init();
    tm1637.set(BRIGHT_TYPICAL);//BRIGHT_TYPICAL = 2,BRIGHT_DARKEST = 0,BRIGHTEST = 7;
}
void loop()
{
    int8_t NumTab[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15};//0~9,A,b,C,d,E,F
    int8_t ListDisp[4];
    unsigned char i = 0;
    unsigned char count = 0;
    delay(150);
    while(1)
    {
        i = count;
        count ++;
        if(count == sizeof(NumTab)) count = 0;
        for(unsigned char BitSelect = 0;BitSelect < 4;BitSelect ++)
        {
            ListDisp[BitSelect] = NumTab[i];
            i ++;
            if(i == sizeof(NumTab)) i = 0;
        }
        tm1637.display(0,ListDisp[0]);
        tm1637.display(1,ListDisp[1]);
        tm1637.display(2,ListDisp[2]);
        tm1637.display(3,ListDisp[3]);
        delay(300);
    }
}
```

You will need to adapt the pin numbers.

But after these steps it should work just fine.

Source: http://wiki.seeed.cc/Grove-4-Digit_Display/

Comment: You will need pullups resistors 4.7K are normally a good value.

Comment: Your answer is false, the TM1637 uses CLK and DIO not I2C. http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/TM1637

Comment: http://olimex.cl/website_MCI/static/documents/Datasheet_TM1637.pdf

The wiring does show the pull-ups. And a note on the datasheet includes: "Microprocessor data realize the communication with TM1637 by means of two–wire bus interface (Note: The
communication method is not equal to 12C bus protocol totally because there is no slave address)". So I believe that, in hardware it's I2C but not completely in software. But it indeed appears that you can put it on any of the pins.

Comment: I'm actually unsure if the pull-ups are on the board already. And it seems to work with regular pins aswel, but then again, there also is a software I2C library. But if it doesn't work, I would use the hardware-wise method.

Comment: Holy s***. The pins A4 and A5 really are the solution.

Comment: @Railsana, so it works by only changing the pins? (With the same code as you used previously, and without the pull-up resistors?) Can you verify that pin 2 and 3 work with normal execution (checking the status of a button and/or controlling an LED), it may be worthwhile to check that out :)

Comment: How does it work on the UNO then???

Comment: Maybe s/he used A4 and A5 on the Uno. ;)

Comment: Well, pins 2&3 and VERY far from A4&A5 or even SDA&SDL. Very weird...

Comment: >  I believe it will be using I2C. spi can use just two wires. the datasheet is clearly written for spi.

Answer (score 0):

4.7k resistors on 2 and 3 pins does not help.

Works great if the tm1637 directly connected to 12 and 13 pins.